# Best way to use ef migration on asp mvc website deployment on server and local development

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-deployment, entity-framework-migrations

I'm developing websites and i want to update database fields as project grows.
to use ef Migrations for adding new fields and changes to db , i add migration base on db on local by connection string like this:

```
<add name="DBConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SomethingDB;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

this moment I have migrations folder with configuration and migration file that has some timespan and when I publish and deploy it, there is migration history  record in host db and I can't add migration history record to host db.
On the other hand, when website is running and some records added to db and I want some changes to project and codes and db,i don't know what to do.
because after changes and adding new migrations, migration cs files in migrations folder and records in local and host db are different.
Question is what is the correct and best way to work with db and its changes during development to develop website on local and then deploy it on server (host).

Comment: Migrations can identify which migrations are run by adding a record to __MigrationHistory. Migrations that have already been run are skipped. So you can either change your connection string as needed, or generate a script that can be run on the deployed database that checks each migration to see if it has already been run on the target database.

Comment: this means that if i have initial migration file in migrations folder and there is no __migrationhistory record in db, it will run those scripts to update tables?

Comment: Yes, depending on how you are running migrations (console, build step, dbmigrator, etc). See [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/EF/Migrations-Under-the-Hood)

Comment: thank you bro.I'll Test these.thanks for your Help.